# how to test sinatra app wrapped inside eventmachine?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, eventmachine

I have this app:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'thin'

class WebService < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    'hello'
  end
end

EM.run do
  EventMachine.add_periodic_timer(1) do
    puts 'hello'
  end

  Thin::Server.start(WebService)
end
```

which I need to write a testing script for. the usual approach does not work because the tests never get executed:

```
class WebServiceTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    WebService
  end

  def test
    get '/'
    assert last_response.ok?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate your web app from your Event Machine code, so that you can require it with out EM blocking the thread:

#### webservice.rb:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class WebService < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    'hello'
  end
end
```

#### app.rb:

```
require 'thin'
require './webservice'

EM.run do
  EventMachine.add_periodic_timer(1) do
    puts 'hello'
  end

  Thin::Server.start(WebService)
end
```

Then in your test file you can require `webservice.rb` in order to test it:

```
require './webservice'

class WebServiceTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    WebService
  end

  def test
    get '/'
    assert last_response.ok?
  end
end
```